# Debugging to Sleep

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging, sleep

I'm having trouble with Debug(f11,etc.) using VS2008-SP1 and Vista-SP1. It randomly, but routinely, puts my computer in the sleep mode. I've looked on the web for similar problems and found nothing.

Comment: Not that it's what happened in your case, but remapping a couple F-keys like this would be a fun idea for tormenting coworkers who left their workstations unlocked when they stepped away. +1 for your inspiration here. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Are you using a laptop? If so, that could be your 'sleep' button if Function Lock is Off (or on, depending on your model).

For more help, we'd need your Laptop/Desktop model, or if it's a desktop, your a link to an online picture of the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

It's a Sony Desktop RB30; http://www.docs.sony.com/reflib/docget.asp?manualid=39973&template_id=1&region_id=1&DL=',600,560,10,10,'Manuals')

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is a glitchy keyboard.  I'd try swapping keyboards with another computer for a while to see if it goes away.